# Hofstadter's Male-Female Sequences: A Curiosity

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a curiosity about the Wolfram page on Hofstadter's Male-Female Sequences:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HofstadterMale-FemaleSequences.html

Do you know what the two graphs represent?
For sure they do not seem to be the graphs of the two sequences.
Thank you very much for your attention.

PS For a study of these two sequences you can give a look at the beautiful page

http://thejavamathematician.blogspot.it/2015/04/recursive-structure-of-hofstadter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like it is indeed the sequences, with a binary representation.

Look at the beginning of the image for the female sequence, with additional paintings from me (excuse the bad quality):

[image: females]

The lowest line (red) correspond to $2^0$, the second lowest (blue) correspond to $2^1=2$, the third (yellow) $2^2=4$ and the fourth (green) $2^3=8$ $\dots$

Now, we can read off $F(n)$ from column $n$. For example the 12th column has a red, blue and yellow dot, so $F(12)=1+2+4=7$.

Comment: Wonderful! I hadn't seen such a representation before. Thank you very much dear mickep for you help: I wouldn't have solved the puzzle by myself!